# Excel Javascript (Office.js) - LastRow/LastColumn - better alternative?

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, office-addins

I have been a fervent reader of StackOverflow over the last few years, and I was able to resolve pretty much everything in VBA Excel with a search and some adapting. I never felt the need to post any questions before, so I do apologize if this somehow duplicates something else, or there is an answer to this already and I couldn't find it.
Now I`m considering Excel-JS in order to create an AddIn (or more), but have to say that Javascript is not exactly my bread and butter. Over the time of using VBA, I find that one of the most simple and common needs is to get the last row in a sheet or given range, and maybe less often the last column.

I've managed to put some code together in Javascript to get similar functionality, and as it is... it works. There are 2 reasons I`m posting this

- Looking to improve the code, and my knowledge
- Maybe someone else can make use of the code meanwhile

So... in order to get my lastrow/lastcolumn, I use global variables:

```js
    var globalLastRow = 0;            //Get the last row in used range
    var globalLastCol = 0;            //Get the last column in used range
```

Populate the global variables with the function to return lastrow/lastcolumn:

```js
    function lastRC(wsName) {
        return Excel.run(function (context) {
            var wsTarget = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(wsName);
            //Get last row/column from used range
            var uRange = wsTarget.getUsedRange();
            uRange.load(['rowCount', 'columnCount']);

            return context.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    globalLastRow = uRange.rowCount;
                    globalLastCol = uRange.columnCount;         
                });
        });
    }
```

And lastly get the value where I need them in other functions:

```js
    var lRow = 0; var lCol = 0;

    await lastRC("randomSheetName");
    lRow = globalLastRow; lCol = globalLastCol;
```

I`m mainly interested if I can return the values directly from the function lastRC (and how...), rather than go around with this solution.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated (ideally if they don't come with stones attached).

**EDIT:**
I've gave up on using an extra function for this as for now, given that it uses extra `context.sync`, and as I've read since this post, **the less syncs, the better**.

Also, the method above is only good, as long your usedrange starts in cell "A1" (or well, in the first row/column at least), otherwise a row/column count is not exactly helpful, when you need the index.

Luckily, there is another method to get the last row/column:

```js
    var uRowsIndex = ws.getCell(0, 0).getEntireColumn().getUsedRange().getLastCell().load(['rowIndex']);
    var uColsIndex = ws.getCell(0, 0).getEntireRow().getUsedRange().getLastCell().load(['columnIndex']);
```

To break down one of this examples, you are:

- starting at cell "A1" `getCell(0, 0)`
- select the entire column "A:A" `getEntireColumn()`
- select the usedrange in that column `getUsedRange()` (i.e.: "A1:A12")
- select the last cell in the used range `getLastCell()` (i.e.: "A12")
- load the row index `load(['rowIndex'])` (for "A12" rowIndex = 11)

If your data is constant, and you don't need to check lastrow at specific column (or last column at specific row), then the shorter version of the above is:

```js
    uIndex = ws.getUsedRange().getLastCell().load(['rowIndex', 'columnIndex']);
```

*Lastly, keep in mind that usedrange will consider formatting as well, not just values, so if you have formatted rows under your data, expect the unexpected.*

**late edit** - you can specify if you want your used range to be of values only (thanks Ethan):

```js
    getUsedRange(valuesOnly?: boolean): Excel.Range;
```

I have to say a big thank you to **[Michael Zlatkovsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/678505/michael-zlatkovsky-microsoft)** who has put a lot of work, in a lot of documentation, which I`m far from finishing to read.

Comment: I guess my first thoughts are :  1) if it is code that works and needs improvement then consider the [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site rather than SO.  2) If you want others to see a solution you think is useful then post your question and then answer it yourself with your solution i.e. don't have the solution in the question but state the problem you solved.  That said.... it seems like there is a distinct question here:  How I can return the values directly from the function lastRC?

Comment: The Range object has getLastRow and getLastColumn methods, which each return another Range object. Do you really want these Range objects? Or do you just want the NUMBER of the last row/column?

Comment: @RickKirkham Ideally I want to return the number of the lastrow, lastcolumn, in order to be able to declare my range later, i.e.: `var rngValues = ws.getRangeByIndexes(0, 0, lRow, lCol).load("values");` . As it turns out, my method above is only as good, if the usedrange starts at 0,0 ... otherwise a rowcount will not give me the correct answer. The work around is to get the index instead, i.e.: `var uRowsIndex = ws.getCell(0, 0).getEntireColumn().getUsedRange().getLastCell().load(['rowIndex']);` I've gave up for now using a secondary function to get this, as it makes use of extra syncs...

Comment: I noticed that if you put ".getUsedRange(true)" it will only do values.

Comment: @Ethan According to documentation, `getUsedRange(valuesOnly?: boolean): Excel.Range;` not sure why that is not true by default! Great find though.